# Как правильно сделать сравнение двух массивов и вернуть строку в каком массиве больше, меньше или поровну

Tags: javascript

Нужно вернуть строку с рекомендацией какого робота лучше купить. Вывожу в консоль результат условий просто для проверки как работает код, а должна быть строка по примеру.

```js
compareRobots([12, 4, 13], [1, 1, 4, 5, 12]);

function compareRobots(firstRobotResults, secondRobotResults) {

  let firstSum = 0;
  let secondSum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < firstRobotResults.length; i++) {
    firstSum += firstRobotResults[i];
    // console.log('First sum', firstSum);
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < secondRobotResults.length; j++) {
    secondSum += secondRobotResults[j];

    // console.log('Second sum', secondSum);
  }
  if (firstSum > secondSum) {
    console.log('Первый больше')
  } else if (secondSum > firstSum) {
    console.log('Второй больше');
  } else if (secondSum === firstSum) {
    console.log('Провну');
  }
}
let resRobots = compareRobots([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
console.log(resRobots);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```js
function compareRobots(robot1, robot2) {
  const firstSum = getRobotSum(robot1)
  const secondSum = getRobotSum(robot2)

  if (firstSum > secondSum) {
    return 'Первый'
  }

  if (firstSum < secondSum) {
    return 'Второй'
  }

  if (firstSum === secondSum) {
    return 'Равны'
  }
}

function getRobotSum(robot) {
  return robot.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0)
}

const res1 = compareRobots([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
const res2 = compareRobots([12, 4, 13], [1, 1, 4, 5, 12])

console.log(res1)
console.log(res2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё сработало, теперь буду разбираться с Вашим методом =)

Comment: Изучите как работает метод массивов ```reduce```, и тогда будёт все понятно